# an e-commerce project with MEAN

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm working on an e-commerce project and I'm stacked in when the customer chose the products to buy I store them in its cart and when he validates it I can't update the new value of the total quantity of the purchased product.

I'm working with the MEAN technologies, for the mongoose models I have one for the Poduct
the **Product Model** :

```
`var productModel = new Schema({
  title : {type:String,required : true},
  imgUrl : {type:String,required : true},
  price  :{type:Number,required : true},
  quantity : {type:Number,required : true},
  ref : {type:String,required : true},
  category : {type:String,required : true},
  descr : {type:String},
});`

and a **user Model** : 
var User = new Schema({
  firstname : {type : String },
  lastname : {type : String },
  username : {type : String, unique : true },
  role : { type:String , default : "customer"},
  password : {type : String },
  cart : [{
    productId : String,
    title : String,
    imgUrl : String,
    price : Number,
    quantity : Number,
    qte : Number,
    totalPrice : Number
  }],
  purchasedProds : [{
    productId : String,
    title : String,
    imgUrl : String,
    price : Number,
    qte : Number,
    totalPrice : Number,
    date : {type : Date, default : Date.now}
  }]

});
```

on the server side I'm using two routes, a **productRouter** to handle the products CRUD and a **userRouter** to handle the user authentication and its cart.
when a user validates its cart I'll clear the cart field in the user collection and insert it into the **purchasedProds** field, I succeeded to do this by like I mentioned above I couldn't update the new value of the total quantity of a purchased product.
I've been trying over 3 days but it don't work...please any help would be appreciated...thanks

Answer (score 0):

totalPrice shouldn't be an element of your arrays. It should be an attribute of your cart object. Something like this;

```
cart: [totalPrice : Number, items : {
    productId : String,
    title : String,
    imgUrl : String,
    price : Number,
    quantity : Number,
    qte : Number        
}]
```

So every time an **item** is added to your **cart**, you should add this as an item of the cart and automatically add the **price** of this item to the **totalPrice** of cart.

Comment: I mean by totalPrice here is the total price of one product, let's say taht a customer bought 3 items of one product so totalPrice here is 3 * prodPrice,

but my problem is how to update the total Quantity of a product after being decreased